# to call a javascript function periodically

Tags: javascript, ajax, function, arguments

I want to call function with arguement periodically.

I tried `setTimeout("fnName()",timeinseconds)`; and it is working.

But when I add an arguement it won't work. eg: `setTimeout("fnName('arg')",timeinseconds);`

Comment: Without arguments, it should be just `setTimeout(fnName, timeinseconds);`  You can't do `setTimeout(fnName(), timeinseconds);` as that will call the function now.

Comment: @Matthew Flaschen - It's in quotes in the question :)

Comment: @Nick, I know.  I was addressing @c0mrade's comment.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can add an anonymous function:

```
setTimeout(function() { fnName("Arg"); }, 1000);
```

Comment: worth mentioning - this is called "currying" :)

Comment: @Yonatan nice, never heard of that :) Do you mean the putting the call into an anonymous function?

Comment: setTimeout is not calling function repeatedly, but setInterval calling repeatedly

Comment: yes, it's a mathematical notion. from wikipedia: "currying is the technique of transforming a function that takes multiple arguments (or an n-tuple of arguments) in such a way that it can be called as a chain of functions each with a single argument."
although I wonder if it's still currying when you're not passing ANY arguments :)

Comment: @YonatanKarni: this actually isn't currying, but a partial function application. Currying is a different concept, currying turns a function that can be called as f(a,b,c) into a function that can be called as f(a)(b)(c).

Answer (score 2):

Use an anonymous function, like this:

```
setTimeout(function() { fnName('arg'); }, time);
```

In general, *never* pass a string to `setTimeout()` or `setInterval()` if you can avoid it, there are other side-effects besides being bad practice...e.g. the scope you're in when it runs.

Just as a side-note, if you *didn't* need an argument, it's just:

```
setTimeout(fnName, time);
```

Answer (score 0):

setTimeout accepts an expression or a **function name** or an **anonymous function** but NO **()** operator.

**()** will start executing the function immediately and results in setTimeout accept an invalid parameter.